# Download drawn item in Folium via Draw feature with Export option set to False

Tags: javascript, python, geospatial, folium, folium-plugins

I am trying to download the properties of a drawn rectangle using Folium and ipywidgets but need the export option to be set to False (i.e., Draw(Export=False)). Is there a way to download the properties by adding to the code below?

```
'''
import folium, folium.plugins
import ipywidgets as ipyw
from IPython.display import display

# Create map (with specified size) and center on USA, include draw tools
f = folium.Figure(width=750,height=350)
m = folium.Map(location=[39, -95],zoom_start=3).add_to(f)
folium.plugins.Geocoder(add_marker=False,collapsed=True,position='bottomleft').add_to(m)
draw = folium.plugins.Draw(draw_options={'polyline':False,'polygon':False,'rectangle':True,
                                         'circle':False,'marker':False,'circlemarker':False},
                          filename='data.geojson',show_geometry_on_click=True, export=False
                          ).add_to(m)

# Display map on webpage
map_output = ipyw.Output(layout=ipyw.Layout(width='100%'))
with map_output: display(m)
page1 = ipyw.VBox([ipyw.VBox([map_output],layout=ipyw.Layout(align_items='center'))],
                  layout=ipyw.Layout(display='flex',flex_flow='column',align_content='space-around',
                                     align_items='center'))
display(page1)
'''
```